# Story ident : Novel about a man abducted to be a pet for aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I'm looking for a book, but I don't know the title. It's about a man who was captured by aliens to be a cute pet.

He REALLY doesn't want to be a pet. There were also a bunch of other creatures captured as well

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Comment: The only other thing I know about it is that he REALLY doesn't want to be a pet, and a bunch of other creatures were captured as well

Comment: I saw it on goodreads

Comment: When did you read it? How long is it? Any recollections at all about the author?

Comment: I've never read it, I saw it on goodreads. I can't remember the author either

Comment: Probably **not** Leslie F. Stone's 1936 novella ["The Human Pets of Mars"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44023) (reprinted in the Asimov-edited anthology [*Before the Golden Age*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?3890)), although it fits what little plot description you gave.

Answer (score 5):

Alan Dean Foster, [The Taken Trilogy](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7420418-the-taken-trilogy-lost-and-found-the-light-years-beneath-my-feet-the); *Lost and Found*, *The Light-Years Beneath My Feet*, *The Candle of Distant Earth*

Goodreads includes this in the description of the first book, [*Lost and Found*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23392.Lost_and_Found):

> he’s trapped in a horrifying nightmare that is all too real. Instead
>   of being a rich hotshot at the top of the food chain, Walker discovers
>   he’s just another amusing novelty, part of a cargo of “cute” aliens
>   from primitive planets—destined to be sold as pets to highly advanced
>   populations in “civilized” regions of the galaxy.

There's also a talking dog.

[image]